# The working copy requires a newer version of Subversion than Xcode supports

Tags: xcode, software-update

I just installed `Xcode 4.6` (I had `Xcode 4.5.1`). I just opened an existing project and got this message:

> The working copy "path/to/my project" requires a newer version of Subversion than Xcode supports.

I am currently using *Cornerstone* for svn, and understand that I can probably ignore this message - but since I want to be up-to-date, what do I need to do to resolve this issue?

[image: Screenshot for warning]

Comment: Check this : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-source_control_management/UpgradingtoSubversion1/UpgradingtoSubversion1.html

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The Xcode 4.6 default use the SVN 1.6.X, but you project's SVN info maybe 1.7.X (That may update by Cornerstone). As a result, when you try to update, the error message'll show. So we have to let the Xcode use the latest 1.7.X SVN.

---

I also met the same problem. That's my solution:

1. Install the Homebrew, we'll use it to install the latest SVN:

   > ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
2. install the latest SVN:

   > brew install subversion
3. Backup the old SVN file and link the latest SVN:

   > ```
   > cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/        
   > mkdir bak.svn
   > mv svn* bak.svn
   > ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/subversion/1.7.8/bin/svn* /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/
   > ```
4. Restart Xcode

Comment: **Accept**. Without `homebrew`, however, svn can be downloaded from http://subversion.apache.org/download/#recommended-release

Comment: The same procedure can also be applied for version 5 of Xcode downloaded from Mac AppStore. However you may need to repeat it wheneven a new update for Xcode is released.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the latest SVN placed at path /usr/bin/, therefore the step 3 will look like this:

```
cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/        
mkdir bak.svn
mv svn* bak.svn
ln -s /usr/bin/svn* /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/
```