# Working copy requires a newer version of subversion than Xcode supports

Tags: xcode, svn, warnings, bundle

I'm getting a warning as 'The Working copy ".../Abc.bundle" requires a newer version of subversion than Xcode supports'. I'm using Xcode 4.6. How to solve this problem? Also this doesn't affects the execution of Project.

[image]

Comment: And did you try following the advise given?

Comment: @trojanfoe which advice given?

Comment: "Try using Xcode to check out a new working copy.".

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15179683/the-working-copy-requires-a-newer-version-of-subversion-than-xcode-supports